# Controlling multiple cameras

Tags: remote, sony-alpha

I am trying to control multiple cameras so that they all trigger simultaneously, or as near as possible. Is there a good way of doing this?

I have managed to get hold of a pair of Sony Alpha 77 MkII cameras, so I have a variety of interfaces to choose from...

Our current idea is to buy a couple of cheap 3-pin remote cables, and hack them together so that a single button closes the contacts on both cameras, or to use a wireless remote with both receivers set to the same channel - however I don't know if any 3rd-party wireless remotes are sufficiently reliable? I've looked at the Sony USB software, but that doesn't seem to have any means of controlling more than one camera, and requires having a PC/laptop on location.

I can set up the cameras beforehand, so it is just triggering the shutter that I need to control.

Any ideas or clever suggestions? I'm happy to chop up cheap cables and recombine them...

Answer (score 2):

The IR remote has a fairly wide beam and if your conditions are right, you could use it to trigger multiple cameras. I often use it for "selfies" and I don't even have to aim it at the camera really. It will even bounce off walls so I can stand 'behind' the camera and still use it in some cases. I don't think it works in bright sunlight but I haven't tried it - it works great at night!

Hacking the cables together for the standard remote trigger will probably be way more reliable. If you isolate things right, there shouldn't be any cross-talk. We are using this method to allow a microcontroller to trigger the camera, and it definitely works - the problem we've encountered is when using auto modes, the cameras will click at different times because they need to focus first. In manual modes it works great.